# Best practices for creating custom exception handling without losing traceback?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've seen some questions that kind of get at what I'm going for, but haven't found anything that quite satisfies my question.

I'm creating a fairly large and complex web server using blueprints in Python Flask. I would like to, when I encounter an error (try... except...), be able to log the error, among other things. Writing the code to log the error and traceback in each exception seems to violate [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

I know I *could* just define a normal method that has inputs for Strings and whatnot, where I could pass in my exception and traceback, but this feels wrong to me for some reason.

So my question is, is there a way to be able to, when something triggers an error, raise another exception while preserving the traceback, where I can have my error handling logic (logging, showing errors to user, etc)?

I'd like my web server code to look like this:

```py
try:
    # some error-prone process
except:
    raise errorHandler # where "errorHandler" is my custom error handler
```

Additionally, this project is Python 3, so I would prefer to use something that plays nice with Python 3.

Thanks!

Comment: "raise" with a parameter throws a new exception.  "raise" without a parameter rethrows the previous exception, thus preserving the stack.

Comment: @FrankMerrow I see, but how would I get my custom code to run? In this case, would I just have to wrap another try...catch... loop around the entire web server? I'm not quite sure I follow, sorry.

Comment: Re-reading your entire question, I assume you know about the python "logging" module.  Once configured, it only requires one line of code to write the exception to a log file.  Standard formatting for exceptions is provided, but you can also customize it.  Our server has tons of code with try/except blocks where the first line of the except is to log the exception and the second line either rethrows the exception or does other error recovery.  I don't know what I would call it a "design pattern", but it is a very common way of doing it.